# Displaying marker data in primefaces gmap

Tags: google-maps, jsf, primefaces

I am using primefaces to manage a gmap. 
I display some markers on the map that result of a query using some parameters passed by the user.

I would like to display more informations when a user click on the marker but I don't succeed in displaying the marker.data.

map.xhtml :

```
<p:gmap center="53.483959, -2.244644" zoom="7" type="HYBRID" style="width:100%;height:800px" model="#{poc_InputManager.mymap}" >                    
                <p:ajax event="overlaySelect" listener="#{poc_InputManager.onMarkerSelect}" />
                <p:gmapInfoWindow id="infoWindow">
                <p:outputPanel style="text-align: center; display: block; margin: auto">      
                <h:outputText value="#{poc_InputManager.marker.data}" />

                </p:outputPanel>
                </p:gmapInfoWindow>
</p:gmap>
```

java code :

```
public MapModel getMymap() throws Exception {
    mymap=new DefaultMapModel();
    ArrayList<POC_LocationsPostalCode> ad = lpcdao.getCodesFiltered(selectedsta);

    for (int  i = 0 ;i<ad.size();i++){          
         LatLng tmpcoord = new LatLng(ad.get(i).getLat(),ad.get(i).getLng());
         Marker m = new Marker(tmpcoord, ad.get(i).getLocationcode());
         m.setData("TEST");
         mymap.addOverlay(m);
    }
    return mymap;
}
```

In this example, when the user click on the marker it should display "TEST". 
Ultimately the goal is to display some informations that are retrieved by a query using the title of the marker.

Answer (score 1):

You should try something like this:

```
<p:gmap ... >
  <p:ajax event="overlaySelect" listener="#{locationManager.onMarkerSelect}" />
  <p:gmapInfoWindow id="infoWindow" >
    <p:outputPanel style="text-align: left; display: block; margin: auto">
      <p:outputLabel value="${locationManager.myMarker}" />
    </p:outputPanel>                                            
  </p:gmapInfoWindow>

</p:gmap>
```

```
@ViewScoped
@Managedbean
public class LocationManager {
  private String myMarker; //Your object
  //Getter and Setters...

  //your listener
  public void onMarkerSelect(OverlaySelectEvent event) {
    marker = (Marker) event.getOverlay();
    myMarker = (String) marker.getData();
  }
}
```

Comment: why? What is the part of the code that makes the difference? Some explanation is highly appreciated

Comment: poc_InputManager.marker.data is an Object not a String so at the end you will have the .toString() of the object as your value. In my example "myMarker" could be some complex Object like 

public class Place {
   String name;
   String Description:
 // ...
}

Comment: If you put a `String` in as data, you will get the String. If you don't, and put an object in there, you can always access the fields of the object as in `#{locationManager.marker.data.field1}`, so no need to create it to a String serverside... What is missing here is (afaics) an 'update' in the ajax call of the 'infoWindow', or is that not needed?